# derivative fails to work

Tags: derivatives

$sin^{-1}(z)=-iln(iz+\sqrt{1-z^2})$

Taking derivative it is:

$\frac{d}{dz}sin^{-1}(z)=-i\frac{1}{i+\sqrt{1-z^2}^{-1/2}(-2z)}$

because ln(x)'=1/x.

But the right answer is:

$\frac{d}{dz}sin^{-1}(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$

Where is mistake in above reasoning?

Comment: Do you mind adding the steps to how you obtained that expression? In particular from the chain rule we expect $$\frac{d}{dz}\ln(f(z))=\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$$ but I do not see how your derivative is of this form.

Comment: Thanks. That was wrong in my calculation

Answer (score 1):

Take things a bit slower:

$$\begin{align}
{d\over dz}\left(-i\ln(iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}\right)
&=-i{\left(iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}\right)'\over iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}}\\
&=-i{\left(i-{z\over\sqrt{1-z^2}} \right)\over iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}}\\
&=-i{\left(i\sqrt{1-z^2}-z\right)\over iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}}\cdot{1\over\sqrt{1-z^2}}\\
&={\sqrt{1-z^2}+iz\over iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}}\cdot{1\over{\sqrt{1-z^2}}}\\
&={1\over\sqrt{1-z^2}}
\end{align}$$

As SoboKevSpace points out in a comment below, it looks like the OP simply took the derivative of what's inside the logarithm and put it in the denominator.

Comment: After the OP wrote *Taking the derivative* they have just straight up found the derivative of $i z+\sqrt{1-z^2}$ wrt $z$ and placed it into the denominator, so there is *some* logic, but not the correct use of the chain rule.

Comment: @SoboKevSpace, ah, I couldn't see the minus sign in the exponent of $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ in the OP's derivative. I'll modify that part of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: And thanks to Ben for correcting my math typo.

Comment: Thats right. I see my mistake